# Excel - суммирование по условию

Tags: excel

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как в экселе сделать следующую задачу:

```
A       B     C      D
1.2017  10    =A3   =сумма от B1:B3
2.2017  15
3.2017  20
4.2017  25
5.2017  30
```

Формула в `D1` должна суммировать все значения в `B` до указанного значения в `C`, включительно.
Т.е. если я поменяю `C1` на `=A4`, формула должна просуммировать до `B4`. включительно.
Пока даже костылями не смог сообразить.

Comment: Для этой цели есть функция СУММЕСЛИ. https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%9C%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%98-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: В С1 значение (текст) или формула? Если формула - почему?

Comment: В примере исходных данных столбец, по которому выполняется отбор, отсортирован по возрастанию. Это - гарантировано? или случайность, и может быть иначе? Иными словами, можно ли переформулировать задачу как "суммировать значкения из строк, где в столбце А значение не превышает введённое в ячейку С1"?

Comment: В С1 список (месяцы - специфика задачи)

В столбце `B` значения могут быть совершенно разным

Answer (score 1):

Предыдущий ответ написан до комментария автора. Комментарий меняет решение задачи.

> В С1 список (месяцы - специфика задачи)

По картинке можно понять, что в столбце А даты, расположенные по возрастанию:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(A:A;"<="&C1;B:B)
```

Comment: Такой вариант выдает 0 :( UPD: разобрался. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы определитесь, что Вы пишете? Если `A3`, то 0 и будет. Если `=A3`, то все считает

Comment: Значит, в столбце А не даты, не месяцы (откуда в месяце число 2017?). Формула суммирует все значения диапазона столбца А в строках, которые имеют ДАТУ *>=С1* (тоже дата)

Answer (score 0):

В *С1* указывем номер строки:

```
=СУММ(B1:ИНДЕКС(B:B;C1))
```

Вариант со СМЕЩ короче, но хуже: функция пересчитывается при каждом изменении на листе:

```
=СУММ(СМЕЩ(B1;;;C1))
```

Значение, применяемое автором в *С1*, невыгодно: и писать больше ), и нужно определять адрес с помощью дополнительных вычислений. Например:

```
=СУММ(СМЕЩ(B1;;;СТРОКА(ДВССЫЛ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(C1;"=";)))))
```

Если в ячейке не значение, а формула. Тут несколько вариантов.

1. Значение в диапазоне уникально (или неуникально, сортировка по возрастанию - тогда сумма до первого найденного значения):

   =СУММ(B1:ИНДЕКС(B:B;ПОИСКПОЗ(C1;A:A;)))
2. Значение неуникально, сортировка по возрастанию - сумма до последнего найденного значения:

   =СУММ(B1:ИНДЕКС(B:B;ПОИСКПОЗ(C1;A:A)))
3. Написать макрос суммирования.
4. Задействовать макрофункции. Для их работы макросы должны быть разрешены.

Comment: Не совсем понял как мы в C1 указываем номер строки. В формуле ссылка на С1 же получается?

Comment: Ответ написан до Вашего последнего  комментария. По вопросу непонятно, в ячейке **формула** или **значение текстом**. Предложен вариант замены **текста** -  в ячейке *С1* указывать номер строки.